# Query an office gateway/router to confirm all routes?

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, netstat

Is it possible to send a 'query' of some sort to a gateway device in an office to see what subnets I have access to? For example, I know that I have access to multiple subnets because we have many computers, DCs, servers, etc. on multiple networks and I know their IP addresses on those networks. But how can I confirm all routes to all subnets?

`netstat -rn` on Linux or `route print` on Windows

Gateway is 192.168.39.254, but I see no other routes to other networks

```
=========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address  Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.39.254  Default
=========================================================================
```

I'm not a network administrator, maybe there is a trick? I can run commands on Linux or Windows environments.

Comment: It partly depends on what (if any) route advertisement is done on your network.

Comment: How can I determine what route advertisement is done on my network? Right now it seems that I can only see the default route (to my gateway IP of 192.168.39.254). How do I know what routes are configured there?